# How to initialize values to two or more variables by calling another procedure using sql server?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

say this procedure have to be called

```
select @className = Name 
from dbo.ClassNames
where id=@classId

select @sectionName = SectionName 
from dbo.ClassSections
where id=@sectionId

select @className as 'Class Name',@sectionName as 'Section Name'
```

the other procedure is:

```
declare @className nvarchar(50),
@sectionName nvarchar(50)

EXEC    [dbo].[testAll]
        @regNo=@regNo
```

so how to assing value to @className and @classSection by calling the above procedure???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create procedures using OUTPUT
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx

```
create procedure spOne (@param1 int OUTPUT, @param2 varchar(20) OUTPUT)

as

select @param1= x from table


create procedure spTwo  (@param1 int, @param2 varchar(20))
as
select x from table where y=@param1
```

Declare variables

```
declare @param1 int
declare @param2 varchar(20)
```

exec procedure using OUTPUT

```
exec spOne @param1 OUTPUT, @param2 OUTPUT
```

Now those variables holds values generated inside spOne

```
exec spTwo @param1, @param2
```

Comment: thanx bro..it worked :)... i nearly frogot using OUTPUT parameters

Comment: @Abdullah  I'm glad it helped! Do you know how to formally accept an answer?

Comment: Sorry... i am new here..i mean i d't know

Comment: Hi @Abdullah if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed something. You can't actually use the return of the proc like that or assign a variable in another procedure, they are out of context. 
I would solve this in one of the 2 ways:

1. Define a View returning the 2 fields you need, that way you could filter the results by @regNo and return its results in another procedure, just like a normal table.
2. Use the return as a OUTPUT field in the procedure. That could be a table or simple 1 of the fields.

Hope it helps...